# Convert XML which has '\n' in content to JSON with keeping \n as it is rather than converting to \\n

Tags: java, json, xml, newline

I have a XML in string format:

```
  <root>
 <tag1>data1</tag1>
 content1\n\n\n<tag2>data2</tag2>content2
```

I m converting it to json using XML.toJSONObject() to get json as passing string in this function

```
{root:{"tag1":"data1","tag2":"data2","content":["content1\\n\\n\\n","content2"]};
```

I want to send the JSON in reply but since it has `\\n` it is creating an issue in the frontend since it is showing \n instead of newLine. How to keep it as \n in content. I m ready to create new JSON after reading the existing JSON but don't have option of using any other xmltojson converter.

PS: I have tried replaceAll() in the content array after converting it to string but it is not working as expected. I m open to suggestions on this way as well.

For this, I have put content in a string as follows:

```
JSONArray cliArr=((JSONObject)xmlToJsonTree.get("root")).getJSONArray("content");                        
for (int i = 0; i < cliArr.length(); i++) {
cli=cli+cliArr.get(i);
}

cli=cli.replaceAll("\\\\n", "\\n");
```

I also have tried "cli=cli.replaceAll("\n", "n");

I planned to put the about cli String in JSON but I m unable to replace \n as already discussed.

Comment: Just to be very clear: both your XML *and* your JSON are correctly encoded to represent the string `\n` (i.e. the two characters \ and n). None of that is *meant* to represent a newline character. If you want to have (encoded) newline characters in your output you must either a.) change your input to actually *have* newline characters or b.) tweak your data in some intermediate step. It sounds like you tried to do b., which is good, but you didn't show us *how* and *how it failed*. Please [edit] your question to include that code and demonstrate how you saw it fail.

Comment: Your `replaceAll` is replacing a \ followed by a newline with a \ followed by an 'n'

Comment: Do yourself a favor and use the `replace` method of String, instead of replaceAll.  replaceAll treats the first argument as a regular expression, which makes your problem a lot more complicated than it needs to be.  Aside from that, be aware that a backslash is not a special character in XML. `\n` is not a newline, it's just two printable characters.  The person or program which created that XML made a mistake by assuming `\n` would represent a newline.

Answer (score 0):

[Underscore-java](https://xmltojson.github.io/) library has a staric method U.xmlToJson(xml).

```xml
<root>
 <tag1>data1</tag1>
 content1\n\n\n<tag2>data2</tag2>content2</root>
```

```json
{
  "root": {
    "tag1": "data1",
    "#text": "\n content1\\n\\n\\n",
    "tag2": "data2",
    "#text1": "content2"
  },
  "#omit-xml-declaration": "yes"
}
```